# Instruments > UI Automation - export script

Tags: instruments, ui-automation

According to the Apple docs I can export a script in the Script pane of the Automation tool in Instruments by right clicking and choosing Export.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

But I don't have that contextual menu item. e.g.

[image]

Any idea why not and how to fix?

Comment: I have no idea how to fix but "export" just means save it to a file. You can copy and paste your code into sublime text or an editor of your choice and save it there and it will do the same thing, and you can import it the same way you would if you edited it within Xcode. I honestly don't use the Xcode graphical tool to develop my UIScripts, I have not had good experiences with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can export that script to file ONLY once - after first export script is representing by file and that option disappear from context menu. (I believe in 'scripts' section on the right of Instruments window You have 'script_name.JS' ATM)

Save option of trace also saves modifications to that file.

FIX:
Copy entire script, in 'scripts' section click Add->Create... , paste script and then Export to another file :)